# How to resolve Amasty module-shop-by-base composer installation error (zlib stream)?

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I'm stuck for the last hours on a Composer install problem.

```
$ composer install
Failed to decode response: Failed to decode zlib stream
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more informations

https://composer.amasty.com/community/packages/module-shop-by-base-2.14.0.zip" appears broken, and returned an empty 200 response
```

First let me tell you that I checked every other issues about the same zlib stream error and tried every solution proposed, none worked.

Every others module from the same private repository are working great, so it's not a right/access issue. Lot's of module non related to amasty are working great too.

I tried clearcache, delete all folder, nothing..

I even tried to copy the module from my coworker vendor folder, but composer just delete it and try to reinstall it, and crash again.

I tried contacting Amasty's support and they say the repository is ok.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried downloading `https://composer.amasty.com/community/packages/module-shop-by-base-2.14.0.zip` and see what you get? Looks like an empty file to me. You need to contact this "amasty" vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that someone updated the amasty account credential to a new one which doesn't had the module in it.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty clear to me.

> [https://composer.amasty.com/community/packages/module-shop-by-base-2.14.0.zip"](https://composer.amasty.com/community/packages/module-shop-by-base-2.14.0.zip%22) appears broken, **and returned an empty 200 response**

(Emphasis mine).

Meaning it's an empty file. An empty file cannot be uncompressed. You need to contact this "Amasty" vendor to ask for support about this package.

Comment: Sorry I will add in the post that of course I contact amasy support and they say that their is no problem with the repository.

Comment: The response from their server says otherwise. You  can try downloading the file for yourself. It's an empty file.